# Help with writing awk in a file

Tags: scripts, awk

I'm taking a class and can't seem to understand how to make .awk files and write them correctly so that I can execute them. Like I have a file `car` which has columns with car names and years and I need to have an awk file that does this :

```bsh
awk '/chevy/' cars
```

I have the `#!/usr/bin/awk -f` and gave it chmod +x but it still says /chevy/ is not in this directory

Comment: the question was to only output cars made by chevy or with chevy in the maker row of the cars file and I know that when writing them in files that I have to write them differently like how awk '{print}' cars can be written as print cars but when I try to write it as /chevy/ cars it just runs forever and does not output anything

Comment: #!/usr/bin/awk -f                  BEGIN { '/chevy/' cars }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an awk script in the same way that you write a shell script, using a shebang to tell the system to interpret it using `awk`

Ex. create `file.awk` with the following contents

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

/chevy/
```

(which executes the default action `{print}` for records matching `/chevy/`); make it executable

```
chmod +x file.awk
```

then run it as

```
./file.awk cars
```

Comment: I am sorry but when I tried this it said that /chevy/ no such file is in this directory

Comment: @IanMcCauley are you executing it **exactly** as I showed above - or are you adding `bash` or `sh` in front?

Comment: thank you sir that was the problem

Comment: @IanMcCauley happy to help

Comment: ya this one error was what was wrong with all 50 of the files I was supposed to make

Comment: hay I'm really sorry if your still there but I have one more problem how would I say do this /chevy/ but only show lines columns 1 and 3

Comment: @IanMcCauley assuming the columns are delimited by whitespace, and that you want to *match* "chevy" anywhere in the line but *print* only columns 1 & 3, that would be `/chevy/ {print $1,$3}`